# plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle') is not working

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to run the optional labs of the machine learning specialization from coursera, and I stuck with some libraries and functions that
I can not install

```
plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')
```

I got the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
in

          3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          4 print(plt.style.available)
    ----> 5 plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')

OSError: './deeplearning.mplstyle' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you may did not download all the files from coursera. Make sure to download all the files, especially, deeplearning.mplstyle, lab_utils_common.py, lab_utils_multi.py and keep them in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the deeplearning.mplstyle file to use the plotting style.

To download this file from the Optional Lab follow these steps

1. Open the Optional Lab from your course.
2. Click on File -> Open
3. Select deeplearning.mplstyle and select download option on top
4. Save this file to your working directory. To use `plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')` as is - make sure your main code file and deeplearning.mplstyle are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not working on Jupyter Notebook this code line "plt.style.use" for importing the file doesn't work. so you have to use other importing funtions on python on vscode for example.

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

Change `('./deeplearning.mplstyle')` to the relative path:

1. Right click on the file
2. Choose **Copy relative path**
3. Replace `('./deeplearning.mplstyle')` with link you got

Answer (score -1):

I make it successfully just by deleting ./