# import error and relative import in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm having some trouble with imports in Jupyter Notebook. My directory structure is as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfxjx.png.

In my `Cost function.ipynb` I wrote the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lab_utils_uni import plt_intuition
plt.style.use('deeplearning.mplstyle')
```

However I got `TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for './deeplearning'`.

To try to fix this, I added `'.'` in front of `lab_utils_uni` like this:

```
from .lab_utils_uni import plt_intuition
```

But this resulted in `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think you need to add the dot (you can find the reason why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)). Do you happen to call `importlib.import_module('./deeplearning')` somewhere in your project? That's what is causing the `TypeError`.

Comment: all i write is like above , nothing else

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76050709/15147088) works fine for me, try it.