# plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle') is not working even after downloading files properly

Tags: matplotlib, deep-learning

After completing the Machine Learning specialization from Deeplearning.AI, I was trying to revise myself on the concepts and the lab, I had managed to download all the files and store them in the same folder. It is a variation of the problem here ([plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle') is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73943812/plt-style-use-deeplearning-mplstyle-is-not-working)). But I have a different error.

```
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for './deeplearning'
```

I tried running this block of code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError, BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid
from lab_utils_common import dlc
```

And got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 8
      6 from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError, BinaryCrossentropy
      7 from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid
----> 8 from lab_utils_common import dlc
      9 from lab_neurons_utils import plt_prob_1d, sigmoidnp, plt_linear, plt_logistic
     10 plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')

File ~\Desktop\ML2\Week1\Files\Files\home\jovyan\work\lab_utils_common.py:22
     20 dlblue = '#0096ff'; dlorange = '#FF9300'; dldarkred='#C00000'; dlmagenta='#FF40FF'; dlpurple='#7030A0'; dldarkblue =  '#0D5BDC'
     21 dlcolors = [dlblue, dlorange, dldarkred, dlmagenta, dlpurple]
---> 22 plt.style.use('./deeplearning.mplstyle')
     24 def sigmoid(z):
     25     """
     26     Compute the sigmoid of z
     27 
   (...)
     36          sigmoid(z)
     37     """

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py:153, in use(style)
    151 pkg, _, name = style.rpartition(".")
    152 try:
--> 153     path = (importlib_resources.files(pkg)
    154             / f"{name}.{STYLE_EXTENSION}")
    155     style = _rc_params_in_file(path)
    156 except (ModuleNotFoundError, IOError) as exc:
    157     # There is an ambiguity whether a dotted name refers to a
    158     # package.style_name or to a dotted file path.  Currently,
   (...)
    161     # either use Path objects or be prepended with "./" and use
    162     # the slash as marker for file paths.

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_common.py:22, in files(package)
     17 def files(package):
     18     # type: (Package) -> Traversable
     19     """
     20     Get a Traversable resource from a package
     21     """
---> 22     return from_package(get_package(package))

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_common.py:66, in get_package(package)
     60 def get_package(package):
     61     # type: (Package) -> types.ModuleType
     62     """Take a package name or module object and return the module.
     63 
     64     Raise an exception if the resolved module is not a package.
     65     """
---> 66     resolved = resolve(package)
     67     if wrap_spec(resolved).submodule_search_locations is None:
     68         raise TypeError(f'{package!r} is not a package')

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\_common.py:57, in resolve(cand)
     55 def resolve(cand):
     56     # type: (Package) -> types.ModuleType
---> 57     return cand if isinstance(cand, types.ModuleType) else importlib.import_module(cand)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py:121, in import_module(name, package)
    118 if not package:
    119     msg = ("the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative "
    120            "import for {!r}")
--> 121     raise TypeError(msg.format(name))
    122 for character in name:
    123     if character != '.':

TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for './deeplearning'
```

From what I can understand and what I could decode of the problem, it seems that ./deeplearning.mplstyle is simply not getting updated as an option for matplotlib, and unfortunately, changing to any of the other styles results in further errors stemming from the other files in the course also using deeplearning.mplstyle.

Where should I put the package argument to solve this relative import issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to update matplotlib library to up-to-date version.

This error appears because matplotlib consider string './deeplearning.mplstyle' as package, not filepath. In matplotlib version >= 3.7.1 TypeError Exception is silently handled [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.7.1/lib/matplotlib/style/core.py#L156).